# splitting text & appending accordingly in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, split, append

One small sample of my data frame is in that format

```
**shop** **product** **location** **time**  **count_products**
store1     ,A,B,C        X          8.30 pm       3
store1     ,G,F          Y          8.41 pm       2
store1     ,C,D,T,R      Z          9.02 pm       4
```

now i would like to split the product column. I know str.split can split special characters & by that I can split the column. The output i like to generate should have the following format,

```
**shop** **product** **location** **time**  **count_products**
store1     A             X          8.30 pm          3
store1     B             X          8.30 pm          3
store1     C             X          8.30 pm          3              
store1     G             Y          8.41 pm          2
store1     F             Y          8.41 pm          2
store1     C             Z          9.02 pm          4
store1     D             Z          9.02 pm          4
store1     T             Z          9.02 pm          4
store1     R             Z          9.02 pm          4
```

I am using pandas & numpy. Can you please guide how can i proceed to get the above mentioned output? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove `,`, [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for creating `Series` for [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame`.

Last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for avoid duplicates in `index` and reorder column names by [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
print (
df.pop('**product**')
.str
.strip(',')
.str
.split(',',expand=True)
.stack()
.reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
.rename('**product**')           
)
0    A
0    B
0    C
1    G
1    F
2    C
2    D
2    T
2    R
Name: **product**, dtype: object
```

```
cols = df.columns

print (df.join
             (
             df.pop('**product**')
             .str
             .strip(',')
             .str
             .split(',',expand=True)
             .stack()
             .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
             .rename('**product**')           
             ).reset_index(drop=True)
              .reindex_axis(cols,axis=1))

  **shop** **product** **location** **time**  **count_products**
0   store1           A            X  8.30 pm                   3
1   store1           B            X  8.30 pm                   3
2   store1           C            X  8.30 pm                   3
3   store1           G            Y  8.41 pm                   2
4   store1           F            Y  8.41 pm                   2
5   store1           C            Z  9.02 pm                   4
6   store1           D            Z  9.02 pm                   4
7   store1           T            Z  9.02 pm                   4
8   store1           R            Z  9.02 pm                   4
```

Comment: Thank you, but you can also click to empty tick under `1` for green.